# How to echo stdClass Object Title

Tags: php, mysql

What I want is echo the title only.

The below command is printed by the following trigger:

```
print_r($results);

Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( [title] => Title A [catid] => 1 ) 
   [1] => stdClass Object ( [title] => Title B [catid] => 1 ) 
)
```

How can I echo just **Title A**

Kind regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just an array of objects, so...

```
$results[0]->title
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! That worked out. But how can I echo all the titles?

Comment: use a foreach loop. `foreach ($results as $res) { echo $res->title; }`

Answer (score 3):

To print just the names you could do:

```
foreach($results as $result){
    echo($result->title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( [title] => Title A [catid] => 1 ) 
   [1] => stdClass Object ( [title] => Title B [catid] => 1 ) 
);

$str = "";

foreach($arr as $item) {
    $result .= $item->title . "\n";
}

print $str;
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [liquid_id] => 1
            [liquid_name] => lfts
            [amount_per_bottle] => 30
            [qty_used_per_test] => 10
            [location_id] => 1
            [liq_req_per_test] => 3
            [no_of_test_performed] => 0
            [labtest_names] => Absolute Eosinophil count
Bla bla

            [labtest_id] => 1,3,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [liquid_id] => 2
            [liquid_name] => sgpt
            [amount_per_bottle] => 50
            [qty_used_per_test] => 5
            [location_id] => 1
            [liq_req_per_test] => 10
            [no_of_test_performed] => 0
            [labtest_names] => Absolute Eosinophil count
Bla bla

            [labtest_id] => 1,3,
        )

)
```